# Randomly selecting n pixels in an image mask

Tags: matlab

Having a mask with size `MxN` containing 0 and 1.

How to select randomly (uniform distributed) select `n` 1-pixels of this mask?

Edit:
I want to select `n` pixels of this mask where the mask is 1. Those `n` pixel should be randomly distributed over the whole image/mask.

Comment: "select n 1-pixels" - huh? Please make question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the indexes of the "1"s in your matrix, and then use `randperm` to select a random subset of those:

```
idx = find(mask==1);
y = randperm(length(idx),n); %take n values from 1 to the number of values in idx
rand_idx = idx(y); %select only those values out of your indexes
```

Answer (score 2):

Another concise solution is possible with `randi` for allowing repeated samples (sampling with replacement):

```
nonZeroSampleInds = randi(nnz(mask),1,n);
maskInds = find(mask);
maskSampleInds = maskInds(nonZeroSampleInds);
```

For non-repeating samples, `randperm` works as in nkjt's answer or just for fun you could start with the following,

```
[~,nonZeroSampleInds]=sort(rand(1,nnz(mask)));
```

I think MATLAB's `randperm` is perfect for the job, but this `sort` line is actually **[how MATLAB used to implement `randperm.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/25354)** before it became a MEX-file, so I thought I would offer it up because I love a little MATLAB trivia.

If you want the locations in order, `sort` either `nonZeroSampleInds` or `maskSampleInds`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
idx = find( mask == 1); % This found all 1s in your mask

idx2Take = 1:5:size(idx,1); % This take 1s on every 5 (uniform distributed)

uniformPts = idx(idx2Take); % Finally, obtain the mask position from the uniform distribution
```

So after, you just need to get all uniformPts.